# Поиск по содержимому файлов во всех ветках в gitkraken (git grep)?

Tags: git, gitkraken

Как в gitKraken выполнить поиск по содержимому файлов, то есть найти все коммиты и файлы где присутствует код. 
Аналогично git grep.

Comment: Греп не ищет коммиты. Это поиск по файлам и я верю, что в gitkraken-е есть поиск. Так что непонятно в чём вопрос

Comment: Ну вопрос, как в gitKraken выполнить поиск в файлах во всех ветках?

Comment: `git grep` в цикле по всем hash'ам, будь то commit ID, tag или branch.